# find the debug port from inside java

Tags: java, remote-debugging

I am starting a java process with the flags
`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket2,server=y,suspend=y`
The debug port that the process is listen on is determined while executing and written to stdout/err.
Is there a way to get the port from inside the java process itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can read this informathion from [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html):

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
```

Comment: It does not provide the port.

Comment: I didn't notice, you should provide a port in parameters -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=<port>

Comment: when a port is not provided, it is looking for an available port. can I know the selected port. I don't want to be dependent on a specific  static port.

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. You can browse through JPDA documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

`String port = VMSupport.getAgentProperties().getProperty("sun.jdwp.listenerAddress");`

however it uses internals of Oracle JVM and will contain port number only if the debugger is not connected.